# Jest - test executes before beforeEach is finished

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I have a test where I have several preconditions in my `beforeEach` method

- check if a client exists (if not, create one)
- check if a portal exists (if not, create one)

However, when my test runs, only 1 of these conditions is met (creating client) and the other one is simply ignored.

Why is that?

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
const CheckMethods = require('../../../methods/common/checks');
const CreateMethods = require('../../../methods/common/create');
const config = require('../../../../../config/config');

let page;
let browser;
let clientExists;
let portalExists;

describe('Super - User', () => {
  const checks = new CheckMethods();
  const create = new CreateMethods();

  beforeEach(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch(config.puppeteer);
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport(config.browser);
    await page.goto(`${config.ui_endpoint}/super/#login`, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    })
    clientExists = await checks.superClientExists(page)
    console.log('clientExists :', clientExists); // CALLED

    if (!clientExists) {
      await create.createSuperClient(page)
    }
    await page.waitFor(1000)
    portalExists = await checks.superPortalExists(page)
    console.log('portalExists :', portalExists); // NOT CALLED

    if (!portalExists) {
      await create.createSuperPortal(page);
    }

  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await browser.close();
  });

  it.only('should be able to make client in super a sales rep and assing portal', async () => {
    ..
  }, 150000)
});
```

Comment: If you came up with a different solution please, let us know... if it helped you, please accept my answer. Both could be really useful for other users looking for the same (or a similar) answer 

Comment: I did add a higher timeout but that did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a higher (compared to the standard one) timeout to the `beforeEach` call? Like `beforeEach(async () => {}, 100000)`.